# iOS SwiftGen, avoid losing changes in plist file

Tags: swift, yaml, plist, swiftgen

I have project with SwiftGen. I need to edit plist file and avoid losing changes after "make generate" command.
But any time when I run "make generate" command all changes disappear.
Please help me to find the way to edit plist file and save changes.

Here is the code that I added in .yml file.

```
plists:
      input:
        - path: ProjectName/Resources/Plists/Info.plist
          type: plist
      output:
        templateName: swift5
        output: ProjectName/Resources/Plists/Info.swift
```

```
    preBuildScripts:
      - name: Generate Info.swift
        script: swiftgen --config info.yml --force-write
        workingDirectory: ${PROJECT_DIR}
```